# Is #EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY tag needed if I build TS segments separately one by one using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming

**What am I trying to achieve:**

I have 1000 PNG images. I would like to have a 30 seconds video with 0.1 fps created from each individual image. Then I would like to create multiple m3u8 playlists from all these videos together one after another, each playlist having videos in random order.

**What have I tried:**

I created a TS video file for each of my images using this command:

```
ffmpeg -y -loop 1 -t 30 -r 0.1 -i INPUT_IMAGE_X.png -c:v libx264 -crf 26 -pix_fmt yuv420p OUTPUT_VIDEO_X.ts
```

Then I created a playlist using the following format:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:30
#EXTINF:30.00000,
OUTPUT_VIDEO_1.ts
#EXTINF:30.00000,
OUTPUT_VIDEO_2.ts
#EXTINF:30.00000,
OUTPUT_VIDEO_3.ts
...
#EXTINF:30.00000,
OUTPUT_VIDEO_1000.ts
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

**The issue:**

When I play such playlist in iOS app using AVPlayer, the following happens:

- total duration is displayed correctly
- all segments (except the last one) plays for 20 seconds only
- the last segment plays correctly for 30 seconds
- player stops playing the video before it reaches the end of the displayed timeline (because each segment, except the last one, was shorter for 10 seconds)

**Possible solution**

I found out that if I insert #EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY tag between all my segments, all segments play correctly for 30 seconds. However I also noticed that AVPlayer needs a lot more loading time before it starts the video in that case.

**Question**

Is there a possibility to create my videos in such way that discontinuity tags would not be necessary? They make my playlist files larger and add delay to start of the video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is correct timestamps in each segment. I believe the `-itsoffset` should do it — `-itsoffset 0` (or nothing at all) for the first segment, `-itsoffset 30` for the second, `-itsoffset 60` for the third, etc.

You could probably also get ffmpeg to do the whole thing for you using the [concat demuxer](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Slideshow#Concatdemuxer) to read the input and `-f hls -hls_time 30 -hls_playlist_type vod`; the concat demuxer will handle "looping" each image and setting the timestamps correctly, and the hls muxer will write both the TS segments and the HLS manifest.

Comment: I tested your suggestion and you are right about incorrect segment timestamps. However argument `-itsoffset` doesn't seem to be correct one. It is an "input option" and can't be applied to output file. It also doesn't change the behaviour if I set it for my inputs.

Comment: I found the correct argument: `-initial_offset 30`. But this only partly solves my problem, because it fixes the order of segments in the playlist. My goal is to generate all segment files in advance and use them in multiple playlists, each playlist using same segments in randomised order. It this even possible or do I need to rebuild segments for each playlist (because of timestamps)?

Comment: @Matevz yeah, that definitely wouldn't work without the discontinuity tag.

Comment: I accepted your answer. You correctly pointed out what is happening and why #EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY tag is needed in my case.

Comment: @Matevz well, thanks. Sorry you didn't get a more satisfying answer.